# Showing that a sequence which satisfies $x_{k+1} \le a x_k + c \cdot b^k$ converges linearly to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, discrete-mathematics

Consider any real sequence $(x_k)$ with $x_0 \ge 0$ that satisfies
$$x_{k+1} \le a x_k + c \cdot b^k, \ \ \ k \ge 0$$
where $a, b \in (0, 1)$ and $c \in(0, \infty).$  I would like to show that $(x_k)$ converges linearly to $0$; that is, there exist constants $C \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $r \in (0, 1)$ such that
$$x_k \le Cr^k.$$
for all $k \ge K$ for some $K$.

(it's fine if we need to add the hypothesis $\forall k: x_k \ge 0$).

**My Attempt**

To make things simpler, I constructed an example and replaced the inequality with an equality.
$$x_{k+1} = \frac 12 x_k + \left( \frac 12 \right)^k.$$

Since for recursive sequences, "multiplication is exponentiation" (i.e. $y_{k+1} = \frac 12 y_k$ has a solution $y_k = 1/2^k$) and "addition is multiplication" (i.e. $y_{k+1} = y_k + 3$ has a solution $y_k = 3k$) I guessed that a solution to the above is something like
$$x_k = k\left( \frac 12 \right)^{k}.$$
This is not quite right, but after a bit of tinkering I found a solution
$$x_k = (k-1) \left( \frac 12\right)^{k-1}.$$

Now, I believe that in a similar way, I can cook up a solution to the more general problem $$x_{k+1} = \max\{a, c\} x_k + \max \{a, c \} \cdot b^k$$ as well. However, this sort of approach is flawed from the start, because the proof needs to go the reverse direction, not the direction I am going in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:   divide by $a^{k+1}$ and telescope:

$$
\frac{x_{k+1}}{a^{k+1}} \le \frac{x_k}{a^k} + \frac{c}{a} \cdot \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^k \le \frac{x_{k-1}}{a^{k-1}}+ \frac{c}{a}\cdot\left(\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{k-1} + \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^k\right) \le \dots
$$